# Pandas: Criar multiplas colunas no DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Tenho uma planilha com as seguintes informações:

```
    NUM_LEGISLACAO  DSC_URL    ...      COD_TIPO   DSC_TIPO
0         323/1895      NaN    ...           2.0   CONCRETO
1       2.269/1896      NaN    ...           2.0   CONCRETO
2       2.397/1896      NaN    ...           2.0   CONCRETO
3       2.380/1896      NaN    ...           2.0   CONCRETO
4       2.489/1897      NaN    ...           2.0   CONCRETO
5       2.997/1898      NaN    ...           2.0   CONCRETO
```

E desenvolvi este código, com o objetivo de criar outras duas colunas com numeros e anos separados:

```
def truncus01():
    xlsx = pd.ExcelFile(file)
    df = xlsx.parse(xlsx.sheet_names[0])

    print(len(df.NUM_LEGISLACAO))
    print(df.columns)
#    print(df[df['NUM_LEGISLACAO']])

    #df['NUM'], df['ANO'] = (df.NUM_LEGISLACAO)
    for i in df.NUM_LEGISLACAO:
        df['NUM'] = i.split('/')[0]
        df['ANO'] = i.split('/')[1]
    print(df)
```

Mas não tive sucesso, ano e numero vêm repetidos, como mostrado abaixo:

```
    NUM_LEGISLACAO  DSC_URL  COD_SITUACAO  ...    DSC_TIPO   NUM   ANO
0         323/1895      NaN          11.0  ...    CONCRETO  5475  1905
1       2.269/1896      NaN           2.0  ...    CONCRETO  5475  1905
2       2.397/1896      NaN           2.0  ...    CONCRETO  5475  1905
265    90.396/1984      NaN          11.0  ...   NORMATIVO  5475  1905
266    90.804/1985      NaN           2.0  ...    CONCRETO  5475  1905
267     81195/1978      NaN           NaN  ...         NaN  5475  1905
268      5475/1905      NaN           NaN  ...         NaN  5475  1905

[269 rows x 8 columns]
```

Qual o jeito correto de fazê-lo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema da repetição acontece porque, dentro do *looping*:

```
for i in df.NUM_LEGISLACAO:
        df['NUM'] = i.split('/')[0]
        df['ANO'] = i.split('/')[1]
```

a cada iteração, as colunas `NUM` e `ANO` são preenchidas (totalmente) com o valor do ciclo (`i`) atual, "matando" a atualização anterior, portanto, ao final da execução, essas colunas irão conter apenas os últimos valores lidos.

Uma forma possível para criar as duas colunas é através do comando [`pandas.Series.str.split()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html), que irá dividir o dado `NUM_LEGISLACAO` através do separador `/` e armazenar os resultados nas colunas `NUM` e `ANO`, respectivamente:

```
dt['NUM'], dt['ANO'] = dt.NUM_LEGISLACAO.str.split('/').str
```

Exemplo (com os dados da pergunta):

```
dt
Out[30]:
  NUM_LEGISLACAO  COD_TIPO  DSC_TIPO
0       323/1895       2.0  CONCRETO
1     2.269/1896       2.0  CONCRETO
2     2.397/1896       2.0  CONCRETO
3     2.380/1896       2.0  CONCRETO
4     2.489/1897       2.0  CONCRETO
5     2.997/1898       2.0  CONCRETO

# AQUI: Cria as 2 colunas
dt['NUM'], dt['ANO'] = dt.NUM_LEGISLACAO.str.split('/').str

dt
Out[32]:
  NUM_LEGISLACAO  COD_TIPO  DSC_TIPO    NUM   ANO
0       323/1895       2.0  CONCRETO    323  1895
1     2.269/1896       2.0  CONCRETO  2.269  1896
2     2.397/1896       2.0  CONCRETO  2.397  1896
3     2.380/1896       2.0  CONCRETO  2.380  1896
4     2.489/1897       2.0  CONCRETO  2.489  1897
5     2.997/1898       2.0  CONCRETO  2.997  1898
```

Comment: Valeu @Gomiero.
solução perfeita! Obrigado.